# MYSQL Select the Sum of Multiple Distinct Values

Tags: mysql, select, sum, distinct

My table looks like this:

```
| id | Vendor | Issue     |
|----|--------|-----------|
| 1  | Acme   | Defective |
| 2  | Best   | Returned  |
| 3  | Ace    | Other     |
| 4  | Best   | Returned  |
| 5  | Acme   | Other     |
| 6  | Ace    | Other     |
| 7  | Best   | Defective |
```

I need a Select statement to sum the amount of each distinct issue each vendor has had.

Output of select statement would look like this in a table:

```
| Vendor | Defective | Returned | Other |
|--------|-----------|----------|-------|
| Acme   | 1         | 0        | 1     |
| Best   | 1         | 2        | 0     |
| Ace    | 0         | 0        | 2     |
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CASE` clause to separate the sums, as in:

```
select
  vendor,
  sum(case when issue = 'Defective' then 1 end) as defective,
  sum(case when issue = 'Returned' then 1 end) as returned,
  sum(case when issue = 'Other' then 1 end) as other
from my_table
group by vendor
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is not working. Tried this: `$sql = "select
  vendor,
  sum(case when issue = 'Item Defective' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'defective',
  sum(case when issue = 'Incorrect Item Received' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'received',
  sum(case when issue = 'Incorrect Item Ordered' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'ordered',
  sum(case when issue = 'Item Not Made to Drawing' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'drawing',
  sum(case when issue = 'Other' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'other',
FROM record GROUP BY vendor"; But that does not work either. No Errors - just returns nothing.
`

Comment: Is it throwing an error (which one), is it giving you the wrong results?

Comment: Also, you don't need the `ELSE` inside the `CASE`. It defaults to `null`.

Comment: Thanks! Removing the , before the from fixed it. Now works.

Answer (score 0):

Final Statement:

```
$sql = "select
vendor,
sum(case when issue = 'Item Defective' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'defective',
sum(case when issue = 'Incorrect Item Received' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'received',
sum(case when issue = 'Incorrect Item Ordered' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'ordered',
sum(case when issue = 'Item Not Made to Drawing' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'drawing',
sum(case when issue = 'Other' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'other'
FROM record GROUP BY vendor";
```